# HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resource failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-type, wav

I have tried to insert audio tag in my application

```
<audio id="beep-notify" src="beep.wav"></audio>
```

I will play this audio file in javascript

```
function play_audio(){
  var audio = getElementById('beep-notify');
  if(audio){
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

It works great on chrome but not in firefox. When I tried to look at the console. There is an error that says:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resource failed.
```

This is what my "config/initializers/mime_types.rb" looks like:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
# Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :iphone
Mime::Type.register "audio/x-wav", :wav
```

But with no luck, it is still not working in firefox.

It would be great if there is anyone that can lead me to the right direction. I have been googling everything about this issue but to no avail.

TIA

Eralph

Answer (score 1):

I converted the `.wav` file to `.ogg` and changed the `audio` tag to

```
<audio id="beep-notify" src="beep.wav"></audio>
```

I also changed my `mime_types.rb` file to

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
# Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :iphone
Mime::Type.register "application/ogg", :ogg
```

And that solved the problem. It's now working on firefox. But it's still not working of Safari because they do not support html5 `audio` element in their browser.

Hope this helps somebody.

Eralph